# Sum of Odd Fibonnaci failing with Higher values?

Tags: javascript

So im running into an odd error, where im summing all fibonnaci numbers that are odd and LESS than a number.

the odd thing is this works with low values, but when I get to upper values past 10 or so.....it'll crash codepen.io

here is what I have so far:

```
function f(n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    return n;
  return f(n-1)+f(n-2);
}
function sumFibs(num) {
    var counter = 0;
  var arr = [];
  //Get all Fibbonaci Numbers up to num
    for(let i = 1;i <= num;i++)
  { 
        arr.push(f(i));
  }
  for(let j = 0;j < arr.length;j++)
  {
    if(arr[j] % 2 != 0 && arr[j] <=num)
    {
        counter+= arr[j];
    }
  }
  console.log(counter);
    return counter;
}
sumFibs(10);
```

Basically I calculate fib up to the `num` and then I go through each odd one thats less than or equal to `num` and add those up.

Im getting correct values (IE for 10 i get 10, for 4 i get 5....etc...)

but if I put in something like 1000 it seems to just crash? and I can't seem to figure out any reason why?

Comment: Huh, im not? I don't think. I calculate f(n) for each "value" going up to num?

Comment: Could you provide an example? Maybe im not understanding what your talking about.

Comment: You should consider using  `memoization`, or an `iterative` approach.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid, I was looking at finding the Fib(N) and was seeing F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) so I was literally thinking that meant to do it for each number to return it....ya what you did makes total sense. :smacks head:. I wasn't even thinking right ha. feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK. I've deleted all my comments and put the same information in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive `f()` function is a logical way to express a Fibonacci number calculation, but it isn't very efficient compared to an iterative approach, especially because you are calling it repeatedly from inside a loop. I think this is bringing your browser to a halt. Within the loop each time you call `f()` it is calculating the specified Fibonacci number *from scratch* by recursively calling itself. So, say, to get `f(10)`, it calls itself *twice* with `f(9) + f(8)` (and then they in turn call `f(8)+f(7)` *and* `f(7)+f(6)`, etc., so even that is pretty inefficient), but in fact you already know what `f(9)` and `f(8)` are because you've stored those values in your array on previous loop iterations.

If you change your loop to calculate each subsequent number directly rather than calling another function you get *much* faster code:

```
var arr = [1, 1]; // start with the known first two numbers
//Get all Fibbonaci Numbers up to num
for(let i = 2; i < num; i++) // start the loop at index 2 for the third number
{ 
    arr[i] = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1];
}
```

With that change in place, your `sumFibs()` function can give you results even for `sumFibs(1000000)` in a matter of milliseconds:

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var counter = 0;
  var arr = [1, 1];
  //Get all Fibbonaci Numbers up to num
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1];
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] % 2 != 0) {
      counter += arr[j];
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log('10: '      + sumFibs(10));
console.log('100: '     + sumFibs(100));
console.log('1000: '    + sumFibs(1000));
console.log('10000: '   + sumFibs(10000));
console.time('High fib');
console.log('1000000: ' + sumFibs(1000000));
console.timeEnd('High fib');
```

Note that you also had a logic error in your second loop, the one that adds up the odd numbers: the `&& arr[j] <=num` part needed to be removed. The values in `arr` are the actual Fibonacci numbers, but `num` is the sequence number, so it doesn't make sense to be comparing them. You just want every odd number in the whole array.

**However**, the return value from your function is *still* going to be incorrect if `num` is too large. That's because by the time you get to the 80-somethingth Fibonacci number it is larger than JavaScript can handle without losing precision, i.e., larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), 9,007,199,254,740,991 (which is 2^53 - 1). Numbers above that start getting rounded so your tests for odd numbers aren't reliable and thus the total sum doesn't include all of the numbers it should have, or if you add too many JS considers your result to be `Infinity`.